# Is there a better way to copy a workbook and hide irrelevant columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make the following code more efficient. It currently works as I'd like it to, but it takes a while and I'm wondering if I really need to save the copied workbook before opening it again. I've read that it's good to do that, but it puts a lot of clutter on screen.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, NewBook As String
Dim newValue As Variant, i As Long, n As Long

newValue = InputBox("Statement for input box")


folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path



Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook


Worksheets(Array("Sheet names")).Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    NewBook = folderPath & "\" & newValue & ".xlsm"
    .SaveAs Filename:=NewBook, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(NewBook)
    With wb2
    Set ws1 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With ws1
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        stopColumn = lastColumn - 12

        i = 4
        While i <= stopColumn
            n = i + 1

            ColumnName = ws1.Cells(2, i).Value
            If ColumnName <> newValue Then
                ws1.Cells(2, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                ws1.Cells(2, n).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
            ColumnName = ""
            i = i + 2
        Wend

        End With
    End With


End With
```

Comment: Now looks like a good time to create an account on [codereview.se], a Stack Exchange site (Stack Overflow sister site) that is dedicated to improving working code in every possible way, from readability to performance; you'll want to post the full procedure/module, and describe the purpose of the code in the title (rather than what you'd want reviewers to do with it - *everyone* wants better/faster code on that site!) -- cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first suggestion I would make without testing your code, is that you can do all the changes in your initial workbook, then `SaveAs` at the end... No need to close and reopen for that purpose.

When you do `SaveAs`, changes are only saved in the new copy.

This will require a bit of refactoring of your code (just use one wb instead of two).

Then, you can use `application.screenupdating = false` at start (and = false at the end), which should significantly increase the speed of processing of your script, as Excel doesn't need to draw the changes on screen.

Some other minor changes... You can set your wb immediately after you declare it, and then reuse the variable for things like :

```
folderPath = wb.path
```

Or

```
With wb
       .....
       'instead of With ActiveWorkbook
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
Added an improved version - or so i hope.

```
Option Explicit 'Is always advisable to use Option Explicit, it will identify any variables that haven't been declared or possible mispelling in some

Sub test()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    '.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'If you have lots of formulas in your spreadsheet, deactivating this could help as well
End With

'Uncomment the below when you are confident your code is working as intended
'On Error GoTo errHandler 'if any error, we need to reactivate the above

'Declaring the variables - i would always start with the workbook, as you can declare and initialize immediately (if known)

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim newValue As Variant: newValue = InputBox("Statement for input box")
Dim newBook As String: newBook = wb.Path & "\" & newValue & ".xlsm"
Dim i As Long, lastColumn As Long, lastRow As Long, stopColumn As Long

    With wb
        With ws
            lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastColumn).End(xlUp).row
            stopColumn = lastColumn - 12

            For i = 4 To stopColumn Step 2
                If .Cells(2, i).Value <> newValue Then
                    .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(2, i + 1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next i

        End With 'ws

        .SaveAs Filename:=newBook, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With 'wb

GoTo finish 'If no errors, skip the errHandler
errHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occured, please step through code or comment the 'On Error GoTo errHandler"

finish:
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    '.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The only issue is that the changes shouldn't be made in the original workbook, all of the columns need to be shown there. I suppose I could make the changes, copy and create the new workbook, and then revert the changes, but simply making them in the new file seemed like the more efficient solution.

Good point with setting wb immediately after declaring it though, I will be working that in.

Comment: As I said, if you use `SaveAs`, then changes are only applied to the new version... reopening your original book should still be the same without any changes. I will update my answer above with what i see as an improved version... without much testing though.